# What does a matrix being an element of another matrix supposed to mean?

Tags: matrices

Lets say we have a matrix A = $$
    \begin{matrix}
    -1 & 1\\
    2 & 1\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

and C = $$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2\\
    -1 & 1\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

The questions are:

- (a) Find the invertible matrix X such that C = XA and express X as a product of two elementary matrices.
- (b) Using the results in (a), find the invertible matrix N ϵ X<sub>2x2</sub> such that A = NC.

So what I know so far is that M would just be the inverse of A multiplied by the C matrix. And I found X to be X= $$
    \begin{matrix}
    -2/3 & -1/3\\
    1/3 & 5/3\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

But after this, im just lost.

- How would I express M as a product of **two** elementary matrices if reducing X to its RREF would require around 3 elementary row operation?
- What does N ∈ M(2x2) supposed to mean?

What i'm thinking of trying to do is to augment a 2x2 identity matrix to the X matrix then perform 1 elementary operation. That will be my two elementary matrix. To illustrate:

$$[\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\\\end{matrix}] *E1 =
    [\begin{matrix}
    -2/3 & -1/3\\
    1/3 & 5/3\\
    \end{matrix}]$$

But then if i do one elementary operation then multiply the resulting 2x2 identity matrix and the modified X, i don't get X back.

Is this how its supposed to work? The problem specified that I only use two elementary matrices but then if the RREF on the matrix, it would take more than 1 step so i'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Please do not add links to outside pages, people here would rather not click unknown links. Either write the problem here in mathjax or put it as an image (the first would be better).

Comment: Oh sorry. Ill edit the post

Comment: $N \in M(2 \times 2)$ means $N$ is a member of the **set** of **all** matrices of dimensions $2 \times 2$. So $N$ **is** a two by two matrix. It's just a "fancy" way of saying that in symbols.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Why did the problem say to use the results that we obtained in letter  a?

Comment: We "solved" $C=XA$, and for b) you need $A=XC$ so we left multiply $C$ by the two inverse elementary matrices from a) in reverse order. Elementary matrices are easily inverted. I think that's the idea.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ohh i see! I get it now, thanks. But now my problem is getting the two elementary matrices to represent X. What's wrong with the process that I did I specified in my post? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need several elementary row operations to get from a matrix to its inverse, not just one..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma But i dont understand why the question is just asking for TWO elementary matrices?

Comment: It's only a 2 by 2 matrix, so two operations are enough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113680/discussion-between-duts-and-henno-brandsma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: See how you can change $A$ into $C$ with swaps (and negating a row)? (these correspond to elementary matrices...)

Comment: Oh yeaaah, how did i miss that... Thank you so much!

Comment: Ah wait. Additional question. How does doing that be equal to X?

Comment: @Duts Every transform is a left multiplication with an elementary matrix. So if $X_1, X_2$ are these operations we have $C= X_2 (X_1 A)$ so we can take $X=X_2X_1$.

Comment: Now i'm just lost, sorry. Which of the matrices do I exactly transform? And to what purpose? Could you tell me more about the X2 and X1 transform?

Comment: Oh wait, nvm for the additional question. I get it now! Thank you very much!

Comment: I wonder if the identity matrix counts as an elementary matrix.

Comment: @DanielV Yes, but you don't use it normally.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Hi, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849741/if-u-and-v-are-two-homeomorphic-subsets-of-bbb-rn-and-if-u-is-open-the), please? Excuse me for the bother.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Hmm with your edit, i also noticed that it requires another step which is to negate a row. Then that will be a total of 3 steps?

Comment: @Duts Yes, you could combine them depending on your definition of what an elementary matrix is.